# Class instance has no attribute 'function_name' for passing object outside class- python

Tags: python, function, object

my class structure is something like this.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.matched_condition_set = set()

    def add_to_matched_condition(self,condition):
        self.matched_condition_set.add(condition)

class B():
    def __init__(self, list_of_A):
        self.list_of_a = list_of_A

    def do_stuff(self):
        for a in self.list_of_a:
            if helper.check_for_a(a):
                print(a.matched_condition_set)
```

in a file called helper.py i have the following function.

```
def check_for_a(a):
    print(type(a))
    a.add_to_matched_condition("hello")
    return True
```

Now if i call class B object,
I get that:

> A instance has no attribute 'add_to_matched_condition'

.
also when I try to get the type of a >> `print(type(a))` inside the helper method. i get type<'instance'>.
where is the object getting lost ?

Comment: What do you mean ```call class B object```?

Comment: Works for me - ```a = A(); b = B([a]); b.do_stuff()``` results in ```<type 'instance'>``` and ```set(['hello'])```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you're getting `A instance has no attribute 'add_to_matched_condition'`; your code works ok for me on Python 2.6.4

To get a more useful type signature (plus other goodies) on your classes you need to make them inherit from `object`.

Here's my slightly modified version of your code that illustrates that; it also shows how I tested your classes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import helper

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.matched_condition_set = set()

    def add_to_matched_condition(self,condition):
        self.matched_condition_set.add(condition)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, list_of_A):
        self.list_of_a = list_of_A

    def do_stuff(self):
        for a in self.list_of_a:
            if helper.check_for_a(a):
                print(a.matched_condition_set)


a1 = A(); a2 = A()
b = B([a1, a2])

print a1, a2
print b, b.list_of_a

b.do_stuff()

print a1.matched_condition_set 
print a2.matched_condition_set
```

**output**

```
<__main__.A object at 0xb758f80c> <__main__.A object at 0xb758f84c>
<__main__.B object at 0xb758f86c> [<__main__.A object at 0xb758f80c>, <__main__.A object at 0xb758f84c>]
<class '__main__.A'>
set(['hello'])
<class '__main__.A'>
set(['hello'])
set(['hello'])
set(['hello'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing `type<instance>` is most likely that you are using Python 2.x.  Because you are defining your classes as

```
class A():
```

instead of

```
class A(object):
```

you are creating "old style" classes.

As to your other problem, we'd need to see the code in which you create a list of `A()`s and pass that list into the constructor for `B()`.  Please add that code if you want an answer to that part of your question.

Also, it's unclear to me why `check_for_a` is not a method of `A()`, and I'm not sure I would name a function `check_for_a` if it actually has the side-effect of altering the object it's checking.

Comment: declaring a class to class A(object): solved it. but what is the difference between the two types ??

Comment: @shubham: See the docs [NewClassVsClassicClass](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass) and https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/